# protractor could not find protractor/selenium/chromedriver.exe at codeship

Tags: selenium, gruntjs, protractor

i'm trying to configure the integration to run portractor tests.

I'm using grunt-protractor-runner task

with following configuration:

```
    protractor: {
    options: {
          configFile: "protractor.conf.js", //your protractor config file
          keepAlive: true, // If false, the grunt process stops when the test fails.
          noColor: false, // If true, protractor will not use colors in its output.
          args: {
              // Arguments passed to the command
          }
    },
    run: {},
    chrome: {
        options: {
              args: {
                  browser: "chrome"
              }
          }
    }
}
```

and here is grunt task which i use for running the protractor after the server is running:

```
grunt.registerTask('prot', [
  'connect:test',   
  'replace:includemocks',//for uncommenting angular-mocks reference
  'protractor:run',
  'replace:removemocks',//for commenting out angular-mocks reference
]);
```

It is running well on my local machine, but at codeship i'm getting following error:

```
Error: Could not find chromedriver at /home/rof/src/bitbucket.org/myrepo/myFirstRepo/node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver.exe
```

Which i guess, a result of not having this "chromedriver.exe" at this path.
How can i solve it in codeship environment?

Thanks forwards

Answer (score 3):

Add `postinstall` to your package.json file and that way `npm install` will take care of placing the binaries for you ahead of time:

`"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "echo -n $NODE_ENV | \
                    grep -v 'production' && \
                    ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update || \
                    echo 'will skip the webdriver install/update in production'",
    ...
  },`

And don't forget to set `NODE_ENV` ... not setting it at all will result in `echo 'will skip the webdriver install/update in production'` piece running. Setting it to `dev` or `staging` will get desired results.

Comment: This helped with my linux setup!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer (pulkitsinghal gave the original solution):

`./node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update`

Comment: This helped with my linux setup!

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the founders at [Codeship](http://codeship.io).

The error seems to be because you are trying to use the exe file, but we're on Linux on our system. Did you hardcode that executable?

Could you send us an in-app support request so we have a link to look at and can help you fix this?